New 40Amp cooktop, should I run 2 wire or 3?
My old 30Amp cooktop finally gave out. Picked up a new one that is 40Amp and requires a new 8 wire. The cooktop is only a 2 wire connection. Is there any value in running a 3 wire with neutral?  The old 30Amp connection is 3 wire with the neutral capped. I guess it could be useful in the future if I upgrade. That's the only reason I could see.  The difference in the cost of the wire is about $100.


Can you post the inside of the junction box where the cooktop wires up to please?

I tried adding a picture

If the new cooktop does not need neutral, just two hots and ground, then using 3 wire cable becomes an opinion.  The new one will have wiring instructions which you must go by.

If it's a cooktop only without oven, there's little reason to supply a neutral, as these devices are pretty much all native 240V only - they don't have an oven light bulb. We are also long past it being stupid to not just use a 240V light bulb, but inertia in the construction-related fields is huge.
An "upgrade" that's still a cooktop only would be the same. Unless you contemplate ripping apart the cabinetry to install a range (oven and cooktop in one appliance) there's no benefit to a neutral wire.

Shouldn't the answer be "what does the manufacurer say" or "what kind of whip does the cooktop come with?"

@Huesmann No, because we already know from the question what this replacement requires, and the question is "should I provide a neutral (wasting $100) this one doesn't need for a future upgrade?"

soz, missed that.

That was my thought too. Only if we're planning to redo the whole kitchen. We have a double oven and a cooktop right now. I don't see changing that any time soon. I'll run the 2 wire. Thanks for the help.
